# Cracked heat exchanger, gas furnace, a scam?

Tags: furnace, gas, crack

Had gas furnace serviced (routine yearly) and was told the heat exchanger was cracked and might pose a CO problem.  System shut off and tagged. Told I needed to replace exchanger or get new furnace.  Got second opinion next day and they found no CO and said previous check (other company) couldn't diagnose cracked heat exchanger so easily (said it takes a variety of tests to diagnose).  They couldn't find anything obviously wrong with furnace, checked CO levels 4 times over approx. an hour, all normal.  Should I get a third opinion??  Think first company was pulling a scam?  Furnace is 16 years old, but want company I can trust....ugh
Liking second company.  Any opinions?  Thanks!

Comment: Time to start writing complaint letters to your local/state regulators and online review sites about company #1. I'd trust the second bunch -- they appear to be acting in your best interests.

Comment: If you aren't sure, get a third opinion, and/or buy a relatively inexpensive carbon monoxide monitor.  ,(You should have several in the house anyway). We haven't seen the unit; we can't tell you which if the two is wrong, though we may have guesses.

Comment: Get a third opinion.  A cracked heat exchanger is very serious business due to the CO hazard it poses.

Comment: Get a third opinion. Also, if you want our opinion, take a video of the burners. Give us a good look at the flame in all the burner tubes with and without the blower running.

Comment: A cracked heat exchanger will not heal itself! If there is a crack it is usually obvious because of the leakage, I am not a pro for furnaces but have cleaned quite a few that the "pro's" said were dangerous with no problems on all but 2 maybe 3 that I could see damage and suggested the land lord should replace the unit, this was a few years back before cO monitor / alarms were available, if a 3rd company cannot show you the crack or leak I would distrusts the first company, it may just need a burner and vent clean.

Comment: You can buy a CO detector at Walmart for $20 bucks and you will know for sure.
EVERY home with a gas appliance should ALWAYS have a CO detector

Comment: For the future I suggest you to go for split system (gas water boiler and separated hydronic air handler) So in case of broken exchanger you do not risk CO Poisoning. Because if breakes the gas-to-water one your boiler simply won't fire (or you'll find steam in exhausts) and if air handler exchanger (water to air) breaks you'll fined just more humid air or, at worst, a pool of water under the air handler.